# Updating turtle background crashes game

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've got a game where if the turtle goes in < 40 distance of another turtle, it would change the turtle background. There doesn't look like any problems to me but it causes the game to crash.

```
def drag(x, y):
    default.ondrag(None)  # disable handler inside handler

    default.goto(x, y)

    if default.distance(scar) < 40:
        default.shape('defaultscar.gif')
        scar.hideturtle()

    if default.distance(mini) < 40:
        wn.bigpic('TrumpTowers25.gif')

    default.ondrag(drag)
```

And here is the full code if needed:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def get_mouse_click_coor(x, y):
    print(x, y)

def drag(x, y):
    default.ondrag(None)  # disable handler inside handler

    default.goto(x, y)

    if default.distance(scar) < 40:
        default.shape('defaultscar.gif')
        scar.hideturtle()

    if default.distance(mini) < 40:
        wn.bigpic('TrumpTowers25.gif')

    default.ondrag(drag)

wn = Screen()
wn.setup(500, 500)
wn.bgpic('TrumpTowers.gif')
wn.register_shape('default.gif')
wn.register_shape('scar.gif')
wn.register_shape('defaultscar.gif')
wn.register_shape('mini.gif')
wn.register_shape('defaultgliding.gif')

scar = Turtle('scar.gif', visible=False)
scar.shapesize(4)
scar.color('pink')
scar.penup()
scar.left(90)
scar.forward(50)
scar.showturtle()

mini = Turtle('mini.gif', visible=False)
mini.shapesize(4)
mini.color('pink')
mini.penup()
mini.forward(60)
mini.showturtle()

default = Turtle('default.gif', visible=False)
default.shapesize(2)
default.speed(1)
default.penup()
default.left(90)
default.backward(50)
default.showturtle()

default.ondrag(drag)

banshee = Turtle('defaultgliding.gif', visible=False)
banshee.shapesize(2)
banshee.speed(-1)
banshee.penup()
banshee.left(90)
banshee.forward(200)
banshee.left(90)
banshee.foward(200)
banshee.showturtle()

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you display any error you are getting?

Comment: @mikeg i dont get an error the turtle window just becomes unresponsive

Comment: What have you tried so far? For instance, did you find that commenting out the line of code that replaces the background image causes the issue to stop happening?

Comment: Type `banshee.foward(200)` should read `banshee.forward(200)`

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is because of this:

```
if default.distance(scar) < 40:
    default.shape('defaultscar.gif')
    scar.hideturtle()

if default.distance(mini) < 40:

    #this line is wrong
    wn.bigpic('TrumpTowers25.gif')
```

the correct code is this:

```
if default.distance(mini) < 40:
    wn.bgpic('TrumpTowers25.gif')
```